# email duplicates on mongodb when hit register button on register page

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, mongodb-atlas

everytime i register with same email on register page it still record on my mongodb whereas i expect it to not recorded

i try to write unique:true on email var at User.js like this

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";



const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        validate: pass => {
        if(!pass?.length || pass.length < 5){
            new Error('password setidaknya harus 5 karakter');
            return false;
            }
        },
    },
    
},{timestamps: true});


UserSchema.post('validate', function (user){
    const notHashedPassword = user.password;
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(notHashedPassword, salt);
})
```

Comment: In the code you posted, there's no checking if the email already exists. Is that missing because you've set a `UNIQUE` index on your (I assume) `user_email` field?

Comment: yes i dont have email checking so i think i should do the email checking on my user_email?

Comment: You have correctly added `unique: true` to the `email` property in your `UserSchema` but if you already have two identical values for `email` in your collection then a unique index won't be applied. Have a look at your collection using mongosh or compass and make sure you don't have any duplicates then restart your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added an unique index on my database by writing
`db.users.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })`

so that mongoDB will enforce the uniqueness constraint on the email field going forward, ensuring that no new duplicate emails can be inserted into the collection.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the const to `const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema` and see if that helps.

Comment: 4 |
  5 |
> 6 | const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    |                   ^
  7 |     email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  8 |     password: {
  9 |         type: String,

it still error and gives 500 ERROR code when i inspect the element